# Why is it not valid to write "from os import path.isfile, path.isdir, scandir"?

Tags: python, import

Is there another way to write it other than doing it in two separate lines like this?

```
from os.path import isfile, isdir
from os import scandir # or import os.scandir
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** You can't. You got only that method `from os.path import <stuff>` if you wanna import the functions/objects from inside of `os.path`.

---

When you import stuff using just `import` you can import only modules (module is a term for python file containing python objects). To import the objects inside of a module you use `from` to traverse upto that module, and then you use `import <whateverObject>` to import that object from that file (anything and everything is an object in python, as long as it's inside a `.py` file). The `.` you use is (generally) to traverse through the directories ('sub' packages?) inside of a package.

How does the interpreter know which directory to include in a package, or how to recognise a given directory as a package? It looks for an `__init__.py` file inside it. If it finds one, it is a package, and thus you can import it.

`import` is limited to accessing `directories` and `modules` at most, if used alone. When you use `from <module_or_directory> import <objects>`, the task of accessing directories and/or modules is handed over to the clause after `from`, and the clause after `import` takes over the task of looking for python objects inside of the module. You see, these are two distinct things - 1) accessing a file/directory, which comes under file system, and 2) accessing the contents of a file, (specifically, a `.py` file), which comes under python's domain - neatly separated in the `from-import` style of importing stuff.

---

In the case of the `os` module, `os.path` is another `.pyi` file (`ntpath.pyi` on Windows) that is alias-ed in the `os.py` file as `path`. Since it is a module, it goes in the clause after `from` in `from os.path import isfile, isdir`. Whereas `scandir` is a function in `os` module, hence it goes in the clause after `import` in `from os import scandir`.